# How to debug javascript errors in generated build

Tags: javascript, angular

We have a angular6 app with analytics tracking.
In Analytics we see thousands of javascript errors, for example:
uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'detachevent' of null

typeerror: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.detachevent')

unable to get property 'detachevent' of undefined or null reference

uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'height' of undefined

The most part of them (about 98%) seems to be related to polyfills js file.

How can we fix them? is there some tool we can use or something we can do to understand where is the error?

Thanks

Comment: Are you attaching the event listener?

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean please?